# Does every launch image and app icon get downloaded by the users?

Tags: ios, uiimage

In iOS projects we upload different sized app icon & launch images for different devices.

If the size of each image is 1mb and I have 10 images in the xcode project. Does the appstore only let the user download the relevant sized image (1mb of image) or is the app downloaded in bulk (10mb of image) and than decided which image is used on run time?

Comment: The whole app is downloaded at once.

Comment: Whole app will package with all resources , if you add 10 images of different sizes then in any device this images will get downloaded with application.

Comment: there is no way to work around this right? like some serverside stufF?

Comment: No, there's no way around it. Remember that the launch image is displayed by the system *before* your app starts executing, thus it's not possible for your app to do anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't such way for AppIcons and LaunchImages.

While application bundle gets created, it will load all the resources file *(All files other than code)* into a single bundle. (.app)

For try out by yourself, you can do one thing,

- Create an ipa file (distribution)
- Rename and change its extension from .ipa to .zip
- Unzip the file to a folder
- You can find all the contents inside that folder, which will be there for any AppStore application as well.

This way you will get exact idea, how your bundle going to be created and what would be size.

Hope this helps.